# Scene is still slow, despite unloading heavy collections

Tags: 3d-view, optimization, project

So I've been working on this scene here, relatively big, got a couple hundred objects, many materials, but it works quite well on my machine. However, after appending a city, the scene tanks and even though it is expected - 40k+ objects 100+ materials, I do not understand why once I've unloaded the collections with these objects, the scene still lags.

The render is a bit slower too - I am rendering only the previous assets I've worked on, and the city assets are unloaded.

My question would be, why is that the case and is there a way to fix it? Ram usage is about 40%, nothing in the stats shouts overload as the previous assets have been easy to work on before appending the big scene.

using Blender 3.4

Pc specs: 3950X, 3080ti, 64gb ram